# UIView frame slightly different when setting corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, cornerradius

I am drawing a sequence of UIViews that touch each other's edges.
But when I set `view.layer.cornerRadius` they get slightly out of alignment creating artifacts. Is there some way around this?

[image: corner]
[image: no corner]

#### Minimal working example (Swift Playround):

It seems to depend on the floating point coordinates.
I'd prefer if there was a version that didn't require me to round the coordinates to whole integers, though.

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let rect11 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100.15, width: 100, height: 100))
        let rect12 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200.15, width: 100, height: 100))
        
        let rect21 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 100.15, width: 100, height: 100))
        let rect22 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 200.15, width: 100, height: 100))
        
        rect21.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        rect22.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        rect11.backgroundColor = .black
        rect12.backgroundColor = .black
        rect21.backgroundColor = .black
        rect22.backgroundColor = .black
        
        self.view.addSubview(rect11)
        self.view.addSubview(rect12)
        self.view.addSubview(rect21)
        self.view.addSubview(rect22)
    }
}

let controller = ViewController()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
```

[image: example output]

Comment: I think you need to offer some more information about your solution before you can expect to get usefull feedback.

Comment: @GlennFerrie I added a working example. Can the question be reopened?